# Disable plugin on admin page

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I have just made a plugin which shows me fb icon on fixed position.
My problem is that the plugin shows on each page include administration panel there I don't want to show.
It may be visited only at user side pages.
Can you help?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if(!is_admin())` to check your code run only if you Not in admin area